# VBscript to zip a folder is not working in Windows XP

Tags: file, vbscript, zip, archive, unzip

I have a vb script that creates zip file from contents of the folder. It is zipping fine in windows 7. But the same if I use in Windows XP, its not working. What may be the issue? Please find the code below.

```
Set ArgObj = WScript.Arguments
ZipFile=ArgObj(0)
ExtractTo=ArgObj(1)

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sourceFile = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(ZipFile)
destFolder = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(ExtractTo)
ZipFolder sourceFile, destFolder

Sub ZipFolder (zipFile, sFolder)

With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    zipFile = .GetAbsolutePathName(zipFile)
    sFolder = .GetAbsolutePathName(sFolder)

    With .CreateTextFile(zipFile, True)
        .Write Chr(80) & Chr(75) & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, chr(0))
    End With
End With

With CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    .NameSpace(zipFile).CopyHere .NameSpace(sFolder).Items

    Do Until .NameSpace(zipFile).Items.Count = _
             .NameSpace(sFolder).Items.Count
        WScript.Sleep 1000 
    Loop
End With

End Sub
```

In Windows 7, Cscript version is 5.8 where as Windows XP has Cscript version 5.7.

Comment: Does XP open zip files in a explorer window. You are using explorer to zip, the same as if you dragged the files with a mouse.

Comment: @Babanna: FWIW the above code works fine on fully updated (now unsupported) Windows Server 2003 R2 (32-bit). The Windows codebase is v5.2, slightly updated from XP's v5.1. The Cscript version is 5.6 (same as XP shipped with). XP SP3 received 5.7, but there was no such autoupdate to 5.7 for Server 2003.